# Problem with differential equation RLC circuit serie

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I am trying solve the differential equation of RLC's circuit in serie, I have: $C=4\ F, L= 1\ H$, $R=5\ \Omega$, and $V_e=20\ V$.

$1)$ first I got the equation, it is: $i''+5i'+\frac{1}{4}i=0$, what I have to calculate is $v_c$, and I know that $i(0)=-2\ A$ and $v_c(0)=10\ V$

I have calculate the caracteristical polynomic and I got that a fundamental system is $\{ e^{-0.051t}; e^{-4.950t}\}$, so $$i=Ae^{-0.051t}+Be^{-4.950t}$$
And now I could calculate $v_c=\int_{0}^{t}idt$

Ok, **first problem**!... I got $$v_c=-4.950A(e^{-0.051t}-1)-0.051B(e^{-4.950t}-1)$$, SO... when I said that $v_c(0)=10=0-0 $ what happen here?

Ok, now I dont said $\int_0^t$, no. I consider $\int$ only, so I got $$v_c=-4.950A(e^{-0.051t})-0.051B(e^{-4.950t})$$

And when I said that $v_c(0)=0$ I got that $$A=-2.020\ B=0.021$$, in that, $$ v_c\approx10e^{-0.051t}$$

but in my but said that $v_c=20+0.102e^{-4.950t}-10.102e^{-0.051t}\ [V]$, so what happen, I need help please... please...

PD; ***To solve can not use the formula that we all know***, the problem is solved by mathematical methods. I need help...

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1611288/11127

Answer (score 1):

So the spectral approach as I remember is you make an anszats $i=\sum_k a_k f_k(t)$ or something like that, you use some theorem to say that each component of the sum is independent so you get $a_k f_k''(t) + 5 a_k f_k'(t) + 1/4 a_k f_k(t)=0$, to get the factors (characteristic polynomial is what you said I believe)

My guesses where the error could be:

I am not sure why the voltage should be the time integral of the current, could that be wrong?

I am thinking maybe there is an $a_0$ component you missed (a constant)?

I don't remember if definite integrals have integration constants so am doubtful the integration itself is wrong though :/